# Alternative to a self join containing max() and GROUP BY to improve performance

Tags: mysql, join, max, self, rank

I have the following table:
fpt_action_handling (3GB big containing 10.000.000 records

```
id     | name   |         action_id        | action_definition  | sortorder  | 
------ | ------ |        -----------       |   ------           |  ------    |
UUID() | name   |   id of table "actions"  |   UUID()           |  INT(11)   |
```

id, action_id, sortorder have an index

Of each action_id I want the action_definition with the highest sortorder (rank).

I wrote the following query:

```
select fa.id, fa.action_id
from fpt_action_handling fa
inner join (select action_id, max(sortorder) max_sortorder from ftp_action_handling group by action_id) ma   
on fa.action_id = ma.action_id 
and fa.sortorder = ma.max_sortorder
```

The query takes like 5 min to complete and it generates a tremendous load on the server.

How can I get rid of the max() and GROUP BY, without losing the requirement of getting action_id's of which each action_id having the highest sortorder? (as action_id column is not unique

Answer (score 0):

Try an outer join:

```
SELECT a.id, a.action_id
FROM fpt_action_handling a
LEFT JOIN fpt_action_handling b
  ON b.action_id = a.action_id
  AND b.sortorder > a.sortorder
WHERE b.action_id IS NULL
```